# Scoping a class method to current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on implementing a tagging system and I'm having problem querying for tagged objects with a scope.

For example, I would like to find all the user's items with a certain tag. With a class method I can currently find all the objects:

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
  Tag.find_by_name(name).items
end
```

However, this has a problem. If I were to do something like: `current_user.items.tagged_with(name)` won't this existing method return ALL the items and not just items owned by the current_user? I suppose this is a simply querying issue but I can't figure out how to change a class method into something called on a collection. I have tried going the opposite way, to get a the collection through the tags, something like... `tag.items.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` but in this case, it's a many-to-many relationship and I haven't been able to get on thumb on this either.

What's the proper way to restrict a query like this?

Comment: Can you show your relationships? Am I right to assume you're using `acts_as_taggable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an association on your `User` class that points to your `Tag` class.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end
```

Then you can do:
`current_user.tags.where(...)`

If you don't already have an association in place, you'll need to create a migration to have the `tags` table reference your `users` table with a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
    class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :people do
            def find_or_create_by_name(name)
                first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
                find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name(first_name, last_name)
            end
        end
    end

    person = Account.first.people.find_or_create_by_name("David Heinemeier Hansson")
    person.first_name # => "David"
    person.last_name    # => "Heinemeier Hansson"
```

So, basically you can define your method `tagged_with` directly into the association!

This example is took from the documentations [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)